Expression interfaceTable->findInterfaceByName(p.c_str()) returned nullptr at inet/linklayer/ieee8021as/Gptp.cc:83
I have an error : Expression interfaceTable->findInterfaceByName(p.c_str()) returned nullptr at inet/linklayer/ieee8021as/Gptp.cc:83 -- in module (inet::Gptp) Network.tsnSwitch1.gptp (id=133)
I cannot find the reason
Here is the part of INI file, where probably can be mistake
# TSN clock gPTP master ports
*.tsnClock.gptp.masterPorts = ["eth0"]


# TSN switch 1 gPTP bridge master ports


*.tsnSwitch1.gptp.masterPorts = ["eth1","eth2","eth3"]


Could you edit your question and provide [mcve]?
